# C++ Polymorphic Data Structure

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

After some searching I've yet to find an existing question which address this issue. My apologies if I missed something.

I have a base class with a params structure and setter. I would like to redefine what that params structure looks like in a derived class and set it via a base class pointer. Something like the following for example.

```
class A
{
public:
    struct paramsType
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

protected:
    paramsType params;

public:
    void setParams(const paramsType& params) { this->params = params; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    struct paramsType
    {
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;
    };
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    struct paramsType
    {
        int f;
    };
};

int main () {
    A* ptrB = new B();
    A* ptrC = new C();

    B::paramsType paramsB;
    paramsB.c = 0;
    paramsB.d = 1;
    paramsB.e = 2;

    C::paramsType paramsC;
    paramsC.f = 3;

    ptrB->setParams(paramsB);
    ptrC->setParams(paramsC);

    delete ptrB;
    delete ptrC;
}
```

I've tried making the base class "setParams" virtual and redefining it in the derived class, however when I call the method via the base class pointer, it has incompatible types.

In the real use case B and C share a ton of functionality which is implemented in A. They just have different parameter sets. I only have access to a base class pointer, but will know if the object is a B or a C. Is there an elegant way to address this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't redefine a type in C++ in the way you're hoping (for good reasons). I suspect you probably want to make the params itself a polymorphic class, but is impossible to know whether this will solve your problem without more info. What does the common logic in A look like that it would need two different sets of parameters? Do classes B and C do anything else besides passing data to A? Would be helpful if you could edit your sample code for how the data is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redefine a type but what you can do is a have a common base class for the parameters.

So you could make `A::paramsType` a base class and derive `B::paramsType` and `C::paramsType` from that. Then store a pointer to `A::paramsType` in class A. That way you can use a common base class for passing in the parameters.

However, in order to access members of `B::paramsType` and `C::paramsType` you'll need to cast down the inheritance hierarchy. You could implement that in a member function. If `B::paramsType` is derived from `A::paramsType`, it will be able to access all public and protected members of `A::paramsType`; likewise for `C::paramsType`.

It will be like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    struct paramsType
    {
        virtual ~paramsType() = default;
        int a;
        int b;
    };

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<paramsType> params;

public:
    void setParams(std::unique_ptr<paramsType> params) { this->params = std::move(params); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    struct paramsType : A::paramsType
    {
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;
    };

private:
    B::paramsType* getParams() { return dynamic_cast<B::paramsType*>(params.get()); }
};
```

A working version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/XWpLD4).

Comment: The idea of having the derived class params inherit from the base class params and interfacing via a base class params pointer solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, just change A to

```
class A
{
public:
    struct paramsType
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    };

protected:
    paramsType params;

public:
    void setParams(const paramsType& params) { this->params = params; }
};
```

Then A can use paramsType::a and b while  C can just ignore paramsType::b and c.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply!

That seems reasonable in this context, but the actual set of parameters is quite large and that would require modification of the base class any time a new parameter is required in either derived class.